# Partial specified in a controller property

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
{{ partial showPartial }}
```

And in the controller I define the corresponding property:

```
showPartial : 'nodes/show',
```

I do not seem to get the syntax right, or maybe property lookup is not supported for partials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Cannot Pass Template name dynamically to partial. if u want to do like that you have write custom partial helper as Darshan suggested [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659368/how-to-load-partials-views-templates-dynamicaly-in-ember-js)

Comment: This is a bit inconsistent in ember. `linkTo` can resolve property names, for example.